# InputStream closes and sonar issues

Tags: java, sonarqube, bufferedreader, file-handling, zip

I have the following code to open a zip file that contains several files, and extracts information from each file:

```
public static void unzipFile(InputStream zippedFile) throws IOException {
  try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(zippedFile)) {
    for (ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry(); zipEntry != null; zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BoundedInputStream(zipInputStream, 1024)));
      //Extract info procedure...
    } 
  }
}
```

In summary, I pick each file from the zip, and open it with a `BufferedReader` to read the information from it. I'm also using `BoundedInputStream` (`org.apache.commons.io.input.BoundedInputStream`) to limit buffer size and avoid unwanted huge lines on the files.

It works as expected, however I'm getting this warning on Sonar:

```
Use try-with-resources or close this "BufferedReader" in a "finally" clause.
```

I just can't close (or use *try-with-resources*, like I did on the beginning of the method) the BufferedReaders I create - if I call the close method, the `ZipInputStream` will close. And the `ZipInputStream` is already under *try-with-resources*...

This sonar notification is marked as critical, but I believe it is a false positive. I wonder if you could clarify to me - am I correct, or should I handle this in a different way? I don't want to leave resource leaks in the code, since this method will be called several times and a leak could cause a serious damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answers here, I could address my issue this way:

```
BoundedInputStream boundedInputStream = new BoundedInputStream(zipInputStream, MAX_LINE_SIZE_BYTES);
boundedInputStream.setPropagateClose(false);

try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(boundedInputStream))) { ...
```

With `boundedInputStream.setPropagateClose(false);` I can close the `BufferedReader` without closing the zipInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

The sonar notification is correct in that there is technically a resource leak that could eat up resources over time (see [garbage collection and IO classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510031/will-stream-classes-or-connections-considered-as-a-resource-leak-in-java)). In order to avoid closing the underlying `ZipInputStream`, consider passing the `ZipEntry` into the `BoundedInputStream` in the for loop as per this SO question: [reading files in a zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667125/read-content-from-files-which-are-inside-zip-file). Thus, when the `BufferedReader` is closed, the `BoundedInputStream` is closed and not the `ZipInputStream`.

Comment: I don't have a `ZipFile` like the question you linked.

Comment: There's no need for a `ZipFile`, the point of linking that answer was to highlight that an input stream can be created from a `ZipEntry`, so it would be possible to layer a `BufferedReader` on top of it and close said reader without closing the `ZipInputStream` that provides the entries.